# About the epsilon definition of a convergent sequence. Is this definition equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, definition, education

I read that it is appreciated to include the context and motivation of a question. I may have overdone this a little bit in this question. To summarize, my question is: Are the two blockquoted definitions equivalent ?

---

I have a little obsession with the following definition in real analysis:

> A sequences $(s_n)$ of real numbers is said to *converge* to the real number $L$ provided that
>
> $$\text{for each } \epsilon>0 \text{ there exists a number $N$ such that $n>N$ implies }|s_n-L|<\epsilon.$$

I'm not sure why. Maybe this is because, this is the first mathematical definition that I've learned at university. Maybe it is because I always thought that there is nothing that I couldn't understand, and reading this defintion made me doubt my own abilities.

Or maybe it is because, that allthough it is more than 1 years ago since I first read this definition, and I can write it down for you at any moment, I can apply it for you at any moment, but it always takes me some minutes to recapture why this definition makes sense. In other words, *why this definition is equivalent with the intuive idea of a convergent sequence.*

So every now and then, I try to go to this thought process. I pretend that I've never seen this definition before, and I try to indepedenlty come to conclussion that this sequence does correspond with the intuive idea of convergent sequence.

The very first time I did this thought process, it took me hours, honestly. But even after a year, it takes me several minutes. This fact frustrated me a little bit, and I began to analyse why it takes my brain so long, before he gets it. This is my conclussion:

1. The number epsilon get introdcued as a postive number right in the beginnning, but it gets only some real meaning at the very last.
2. The part $\forall n>N$. For some reason, it takes me time before I get to uderstand that this just means, let's restrict the domain of $s_n$ to $n>N$.
3. The phrase $|s_n-L|<\epsilon$. It takes me some time before I see that this means $s_n \in (L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon)$.
4. The nature of this logical expression is just complicated: $\forall ... \exists ... \forall ... : $

So, as I've analysed this so intensly now, I don't think it will ever cost me more than one minute to go through my thought process (of indepedenlty understanding that the definition corresponds with the intuive idea of a convergent sequence).

But I am also thinking, could I rephrase this definition so that it is more intuive ? Well, it hard to judge that, but at least I've tried, **and I am especially curious if this definition is equivalent with the standard one**:

> A sequence $(s_n)$ converges to $L$ if there exists a function 
>    $f:\mathbb{R}_{>0}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that
>
> $$\forall x >0: (L-x,L+x)\supset
>  \{s_n : n>f(x)\}$$

or using more common notation:

> A sequence $(s_n)$ converges to $L$ if there exists a function 
>    $N:\mathbb{R}_{>0}\to\mathbb{R}:\epsilon \mapsto N(\epsilon)$ such that
>
> $$\forall \epsilon >0:(L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon)\supset
>  \{s_n : n>N(\epsilon)\}$$

Comment: Btw, I'm not sure what the standard way is for writing the image set of a sequence. I also thought about writing $s_{n>N(\epsilon)}$ or $s(\{n\in \mathbb{N}: n>N(\epsilon)\})$.

Comment: I think that the second one (that with the function $N$) is equivalent to the standard definition.

Comment: I maybe missing some tiny logical bit but I think your definitions are fine and equivalent to the usual one. What I can't understand is why would *anyone* think these definitions are, in some more or less mundane sense, "more intuitive" than the usual one...you could also "word out" the definition: The limit of $\;\{s_n\}\;$ is *a number* $\;L\;$ iff for any $\;\epsilon\;$ neighbourhood of $\;L\;$, **all but a finite** number of elements of the sequence are within that neighbourhood.

Comment: @Donantonio If I see this definition, I immediately see the intuitive picture, of a convergent sequence. With the normal definition, I need to think hard to get that picture. But this probably very individual different :-) You definition is hard for me, as I don't know what a neigbourhood is :P

Comment: $(L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon)$ is an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $L$.

Comment: You've your answer to whata neighbourhood is, @Kasper, and pay attention to the fact that if you know this simple, basic definition then what I wrote above is, imo, easily graspable.

Comment: Yepz it is. The cool thing of your definition, is that we can leave out this whole function $N(\epsilon)$. I think it would be good, for a real analysis course, to first give a definition like this. Show why such definition corresponds with the intuitive idea. And then show that this equivalent with the "normal" defintion, which is more usefull for actually proving that a sequence is convergent.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661999/are-infinitesimals-dangerous/2008505#2008505

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The standard definition implies your definition:**
Let $x>0$. By the normal definition, there exists a $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $|s_n-L|<x$. Define $f(x)=N$. We can repeat this step for every arbitrary $x>0$, so in this way we construct a function $f:\mathbb{R}_{>0}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that for every $x>0$ we have that $n>f(x)$ implies that $|s_n-L|<x$. We are now going to prove that $(L-x,L+x)\supset
 \{s_n : n>f(x)\}$. Let $n>f(x)$. Then $|s_n-L|<x$, so $s_n 
\in (L-x,L+x)$.

**Your definition implies the standard definition:**
Let $\epsilon >0$. By your definition, there exist a function $N:\mathbb{R}_{>0}\to\mathbb{R}:\epsilon \mapsto N(\epsilon)$ such that
$$(L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon)\supset
 \{s_n : n>N(\epsilon)\}$$

Choose $N=N(\epsilon)$. Then if $n>N$ then $s_n \in (L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon)$. Therefore $n>N$ implies $|s_n-L|<\epsilon$.

So both definitions are equivalent.